# Jquery .on 'click' event doesn't work in a partial view rendered inside modal popup

Tags: modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a main view that has a button "AddSkillBtn" which on clicked shows a modal popup witha partial view inside. Works fine so far. I have a link inside the partial view "addAnotherSkill" which on clicked has to show an alert. However, the click event doesn't get fired at all. Please find below the code snippet -  Any help much appreciated!!

```js
**jQuery:** 

$('#AddSkillBtn').click(function (e) {    
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
                type: "POST"
                
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#AddContainer").html(result);

                    $('#AddModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });

$("#addAnotherSkill").on('click', function () {
           
            alert("Hi!!");

        });
```

```html
**Main View**

<p><a id="AddSkillBtn" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary">Add new Skill</a></p>


<div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="AddModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AddLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="AddLabel">Add New Skills</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="AddContainer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

   
**Partial View rendered in the modal popup has**

        <a id="addAnotherSkill" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Another</a> //clicking on this link does nothing
```

Comment: Looks like the element with `id="addAnotherSkill"` is being added dynamically,in which case it needs to be `$(document).on('click', '#addAnotherSkill', function () {` (change document to the closest ancestor which exists when the page is first rendered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element with `id="addAnotherSkill"` is being added to DOM dynamically. In order to use event delegation using the `.on()` function, it needs to be

```
$(document).on('click', '#addAnotherSkill', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

Note you should change `document` to the closest ancestor of the element which exists when the page is first loaded.

Note also the use of `e.preventDefault()` which means that you can just use `<a id="addAnotherSkill" href="#">` (my preference but I have seen arguments for and against - for example [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0))